# How To Have home page products of specific Category magento 2.1

Tags: magento, html, categories, magento2

I wanted to show products from specific Category that is loaded in the home page with pagination
It was pretty straightforward by adding `category_id="3"` in magento 1.X but it is with this on magento 2.x.

Please help me achieving this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Login to Magento Admin page and go to Content->Pages.

[image]

Select the Edit option from the Home Page

[image]

Click the Content tab from Left Side navigation section

[image]

Remove the existing content from that page and click the widget icon from the editor.

[image]

Select the widget type as ‘Catalog Products List’ and enter the basic information. In the bottom you can see the conditions to add.  Select the option ‘Category’ and select the category you want to display in home page and click “Insert Widget” button.

[image]

Save the page and clear the cache. Now you will be able to see the products of the specific category in the Home Page.